# Can I send my bounty to someone who answered another question?

Tags: discussion, support, bounties

I put a bounty on my question and I found the answer (or at least led me to it) in another question. Can I send that person the bounty?

See here: [Razor Syntax gives errors in View before compiling (No intellisense)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941675/razor-syntax-gives-errors-in-view-before-compiling-no-intellisense)

Comment: No, but you could encourage them to answer your question. Or if the questions are duplicates you could ask a mod to merge them rather than just marking your as a duplicate, which hopefully would let you directly award their answer.

Comment: Removed the bug tag. This is not a bug report, possibly a feature request there, but I don't see how anyone can construe this as a bug.

Comment: @Oded It would not let me post it without adding another tag. That warning message to add tags is very vague and hard to understand.

Comment: Meta sites require a post to have (at least) one of several tags - if you remove a required tag, a different one of those is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.

However, if you really want to award that answer on the other question, you could start a bounty on that question. Choose the *"reward existing answer"* option. Wait 2 days, and give that answer the bounty you placed.

For more info on bounties, read the [bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

[@curiousdannii](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239966/can-i-send-my-bounty-to-someone-who-answered-another-question#comment786195_239966) came up with an interesting idea that may just work in some cases. Raise a custom mod flag and ask for the other question to be merged to the question you placed a bounty on. However, they must be exact duplicates and no guarantee a mod would merge them or the way you want. However, not sure if this technique has ever been used in a case like this before, so can't say if it would for sure work.

Comment: Most mods would be sympathetic so it would be worth a try asking.

Comment: It's very similar issues, but the answer to mine was slightly different than to the other question.